# CSS Navbar contents scaling

Tags: html, css, web, nav

Hi there I was just wondering what would be the best way to scale my navbar so that the size of the boxes are relative to the screen width?

Just trying to have it a little bit responsive. Thanks

[image: Full screen]

[image: Pressed F12 to reduce width of screen]

Here is the CSS:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background2.jpg");
}
#navbar ul {
  padding: 5px;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
#navbar ul li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}
#navbar a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 15px 162.5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: auto;
  color: white;
  background-color: #003333;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: #c2d6d6;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: #003333;
  width: 100%;
  height: 68px;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
a {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #003333;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#navbar #currentpage a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background-color: #c2d6d6;
}
```

[EDIT] Thank you for all your answers!

Comment: please you can put your htnl code in snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try CSS3 vh and vw units

for details check link bellow

check this

[css3 units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

[viewport-sized-typography](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

[viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

Answer (score 3):

```css
body {
  background-image: url("background2.jpg");
}
a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #003333;
  transition-duration: 1s;
}
#navbar {
  background-color: #003333;
  border-radius: 15px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: table;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#navbar ul li {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
#navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  background-color: #033;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-family: Courier New;
}
#navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: #c2d6d6;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

#navbar #currentpage a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: line-through;
  background-color: #c2d6d6;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navbar">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Biography</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Well if all you want is to scale the menu, I'd use the viewport relative units (`vw` for width and `vh` for height, both acting as percentage of the size of viewport).

You can also try using `CSS` [`transform: scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale) function and\or [`zoom`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/zoom) property.

Note that both are still working drafts (though widely supported by modern browsers).

For responsiveness I'd send you to read a bit more about [`@media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>equal width</title>

<style type="text/css">
html { font: 0.75em/1.5 sans-serif; }
.tabs { margin:  0; padding: 0; list-style: none; display: table; table-layout: fixed; width: 100%; }
.tabs__item { display: table-cell; } 
.tabs__link { display: block; }
.primary-nav { text-align: center; border-radius: 4px; overflow: hidden; }
.primary-nav a { padding: 1em; background-color: #BADA55; color: #fff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none; }
.primary-nav a:hover { background-color: #A3C43B; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <ul class="tabs  primary-nav">
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">About</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Work</a>
    </li>
    <li class="tabs__item">
        <a href="#" class="tabs__link">Contact</a>
    </li>
</ul>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For Responsive Menu you can refer the below link. http://www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/